# Getting message element through wcf intercepter

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, interceptor

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
       MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
      Message reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
      XmlDocument NewbodyDoc = new XmlDocument();
      NewbodyDoc.Load(reply.ToString);
      XmlNodeList strval = NewbodyDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SSNIdentification");
        if (strval.Count > 0)
        {
            XmlNode xmlNode = strval.Item(0);

              string strRval = xmlNode.InnerText;}
```

I was trying to extract one element from the input message using WCF Interceptor. but i am getting error at Line  NewbodyDoc.Load(reply.ToString);

Does any one has idea what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToString()` is a method and you have missed the angular braces

Change this

```
 NewbodyDoc.Load(reply.ToString);
```

To

```
 NewbodyDoc.Load(reply.ToString());
```

Happy Coding :)